# Clicking the print button in chartFx doesn't bring the print dialog

Tags: printing, dialog, chartfx

I have ChartFX 7.0 for win forms and the toolbar is set to Visible, but when I click the "Print..." button nothing happens.

Weird thing is that in some environments I'm able to reproduce this and in others I can't.

Does anybody knows how to access the event generated by this "Print..." button or what the heck is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: I know why this is happening, 64 bit environments are not supported by this "Print" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print button is not working in 64 bit operating systems. This might require an update from ChartFX.